# Github notification icon decoder sheet?

Tags: github

When viewing unread notifications on Github they prefix them with these cute little icons which, AFAIK, they do not bother to actually *define* anywhere...

Anyone know the difference? Or even better where is the legend that defines all their little icons? (Hovering over them does nothing.)

And that blue dot next to some but not all of the unread notifications?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

GitHub uses the [Octicons](https://primer.style/octicons/) icon set. (An older version but with a better summary of icons can be found [here](https://styleguide.github.com/primer/components/octicons/)). The purpose of each icon can be inferred from its name in most cases.

In your screenshot, the green icon denotes an open issue, and the red one denotes a closed issue.